# Unable to access the Roles from Authorize Attribute in IActionModelConvention implemented Apply Method

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, authentication, oauth

I am trying here to parse the Roles from Action Method Applied Authorize filter. But I am only able to get in Runtime through a quick watch. But Unable to get it via LINQ query.

```
internal class AuthorizeModelConvention : IActionModelConvention
    { 
        public void Apply(ActionModel action)
        {
            IReadOnlyList<object> actionAttributes = action.Attributes;

            if (!actionAttributes.Select(x => x.GetType()).Any(x => x.Name.Contains("AllowAnonymousAttribute")))
            { 
                action.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter("auth-policy")); 
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Any update? Does my reply solve your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, I suggest you could try to use below codes to check if the authorize attribute's roles value is "admin" or not.

```
 actionAttributes.Select(t => t.GetType().GetProperties().ToList().Select(x => x.GetValue(t, null)).ToList()).Any(x => x.Contains("admin"));
```

Result:

[image]